# Convert Float32 to C++ float variable

Tags: ros-melodic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to convert a Float32 type std_msg into a float variable. Following is the code I have at the moment.

```
void update_yaw(const std_msgs::Float32 &yaw)
{
    std_msgs::Float32 imu;
    imu = *yaw;
    fromIMU::Yaw = float(imu.data);
    ROS_INFO("Yaw updated");
}
```

But when I try to compile, the following error comes.

```
/home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp: In function ‘void update_yaw(const Float32&)’:
/home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp:89:11: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘const Float32 {aka const std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >}’)
     imu = *yaw;
           ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/complex.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:404:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator*(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
     operator*(const _Tp& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:404:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp:89:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
     imu = *yaw;
            ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/complex.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:395:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const _Tp&)
     operator*(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const _Tp& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:395:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp:89:12: note:   ‘const Float32 {aka const std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >}’ is not derived from ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’
     imu = *yaw;
            ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/complex.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/policies/error_handling.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/special_functions/round.hpp:14,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/time.h:58,
                 from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:38,
                 from /home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:386:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> std::complex<_Tp> std::operator*(const std::complex<_Tp>&, const std::complex<_Tp>&)
     operator*(const complex<_Tp>& __x, const complex<_Tp>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:386:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/padmal/catkin_ws/src/ouster_example/ouster_ros/src/merger_node.cpp:89:12: note:   ‘const Float32 {aka const std_msgs::Float32_<std::allocator<void> >}’ is not derived from ‘const std::complex<_Tp>’
     imu = *yaw;
            ^~~
```

What could be the issue here? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358606/convert-float32-to-c++-float-variable/) by [Padmal](https://answers.ros.org/users/37219/padmal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your function signature shows you get a reference to  `yaw`. It is not a pointer.
So you don't need to dereference it. Simply `imu = yaw` should suffice.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3